# VBA, criar uma macro para que eu possa comparar duas listas de nomes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, visual-basic-6, excel-vba

Estou com dificuldades para criar uma macro que possa verificar a igualdade entre cada célula de uma lista e, se ambos forem diferentes, deixar uma linha em branco acima da célula.

Por exemplo:

> A  A
>
> B  C
>
> C D
>
> D E
>
> E F
>
> G H

Deixando:

> A A
>
> B
>
> C C
>
> D D
>
> E E
>
> F
>
> G
>
> H

Tenho que verificar se as duas listas de nomes são iguais, e para cada erro tenho que fazer uma notificação (por isso a célula vazia). Não posso misturar os erros de cada lista.

O Código que tenho até então é meio desestimulante.

```
 Private Sub compare_cells(ByVal Target1 As Range, ByVal Target2 As Range)
If Target1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target2 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets(Target1.Parent.Name)
Set ws2 = Sheets(Target2.Parent.Name)
    If Target1.Value <> Target2.Value Then
        ' If they don't match place your code here
        ws1.Range(Target1.Row & ":" & Target1.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        ws2.Range(Target2.Row & ":" & Target2.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If

End Sub
```

Estava tentando fazer funcionar dessa maneira:

```
    Range("A3:C3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B4").Select
```

Mas estou com dificuldade de fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, nesse caso poderia tentar o seguinte código, mas não repara a bagunça. E se precisar ajustar algo, me avisa!

ALTERADO:

```
Sub Organizar()
Dim aw As String
Dim ln As Long
aw = ActiveSheet.Name
For i = 1 To 3
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Next
    Range("D1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("E1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ln = ActiveSheet.Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(aw).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(aw).Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A1") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(aw).Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:A" & ln)
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ln = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$" & ln).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],C[2],1,0),"""")"
    Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],C[2],1,0),"""")"
    ln = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    Range("B1:C1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:C" & ln)
    Columns("A:F").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("A:A").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("C:E").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Esta macro não funcionou no exemplo acima, ela cria uma linha nova com todos os dados das duas listas juntos e move as outras listas para a direita. O que eu posso fazer?

Comment: Chegou a copiar ela inteira, até a parte "end sub"? Primeiro ela faz isso que citou, depois elimina duplicatas e organiza, e ao final exclui a nova linha, deixando somente o resultado desejado. Tente novamente!

Comment: Tentei novamente e utilizei o depurador. Nele, o código trava no

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(planilha).Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A1") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNorma`

Comment: Amigo, alterei a macro. Imagino que já tenha até resolvido. Mas precisei viajar, só hoje voltei pro excel. Abs